# How to delete white spaces of a text in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using the twig template engine while using symfony2. I'm trying to find a way to delete the white spaces from a text.

For example, `I play` shall become `Iplay`.

I've tried:

- [Spaceless](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html)
- [Trim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

First let's see what you tried and why that wasn't working:

- Spaceless: is not working because "Use the spaceless tag to remove whitespace **between** HTML tags, **not whitespace within** HTML tags **or whitespace in plain text**" see [spaceless documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html#spaceless).
- Trim: is not working because "The trim filter strips whitespace (or other characters) from the **beginning** and **end** of a string" see [trim documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html#trim).

What you need to use is the following:

```
{{ 'Some Text With Spaces'|replace({' ': ''}) }}
```

This will output:

```
SomeTextWithSpaces
```

More details in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html#replace).

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying `{{ 'my string'|replace(' ', '') }}` and it would not work. If I replaced the replace with string to something other than nothing, it'd work. Odd.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
{{ "I plays"|replace({' ':''}) }}
```

Comment: @KubiRoazhon: then are you 100% sure these are blank spaces?

Comment: The replace method function it's a little bit different see [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html ).

Comment: @briosheje for sure. I've tested it with a simple text => I play :/

Comment: try `replace({' ':''})`.. Not sure though, I've always seen that in the syntax shown by Jayesh

Comment: I submitted an edit to this answer in order to avoid misunderstandings by other users.

Comment: An edit that should've  be rejected as it clearly interferes with the posted answer

Comment: Well, I don't mind some less points of reputation if this prevents having people ranting around because they just copy/pasted wrong stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also create your own filter to do that

**Example :**

```
class MyExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('removeWhiteSpace', array($this, 'removeWhiteSpace'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function removeWhiteSpace($string)
    {

       return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
    }
}
```

Declare it as service :

```
myextensions.twig_extension:
      class: YourProject\YourBundle\Twig\MyExtensions
      public: false
      tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

And call it in yours twig template :

```
{{ "Test remove white space"|removeWhiteSpace }}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was not working when string contains non-breaking whitespaces:

```
stringWithNonBreakingWhitespace|replace({' ':''}
```

To replace non-braking whitespace you have to use escape sequence:

```
stringWithNonBreakingWhitespace|replace({'\xc2\xa0':''}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the spaceless filter to remove whitespace between HTML tags, not whitespace within HTML tags or whitespace in plain text:

```
{{ "<div>
        <strong>foo</strong>
    </div>"|spaceless }}
```

You can combine spaceless with the apply tag to apply the transformation on large amounts of HTML:

```
{% apply spaceless %}
    <div>
        <strong>foo</strong>
    </div>
{% endapply %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar need while optimizing my templates. Here's a quick way to reduce HTML whitespace in Twig:

```
{% if primary -%}
    <div class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Primary tabs'|t }}</div>
    <ul>{{ primary }}</ul>
{%- endif %}
{%- if secondary -%}
    <div class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Secondary tabs'|t }}</div>
    <ul>{{ secondary }}</ul>
{%- endif %}
```

Adding "-" inside your {%- if -%} and {%- endif -%} tags cuts out the extra spaces.

Hope this helps!